# Parse json object when node server is started

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, eventemitter

I need to parse json object when the node server.js(which is my entry point to the program) is started ,the parse of the json file is done in diffrent module in my project.
I've two questions

- Is it recommended to invoke the parse function with event in the server.js file
- I read about the event.emiter but not sure how to invoke function
  from different module...example will be very helpful

I've multiple JSON files

**UPDATE to make it more clear**

if I read 3 json file object (50 lines each) when the server/app is loaded (server.js file) this will be fast I guess. my scenario is that the list of the valid path's for the express call is in this json files

app.get('/run1', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

So run1 should be **defined** in the json file(like **white list of path's**) if user put run2 which I not defined I need to provide error so I think that when the server is up to do this call and keep this obj with all config valid path and when user make a call just get this object which alreay parsed (when the server loaded ) and verify if its OK, I think its better approach instead doing this on call

**UPDATE 2**

I'll try explain more simple.
Lets assume that you have **white list** of path which you should listen,
like run1

```
app.get('/run1', function
```

Those path list are defined in jsons files inside your project under specific folder,before every call to your application via express you should verify that this path that was requested is in the path list of json. **this is given**. now how to do it.

Currently I've develop module which seek the json files in this and find if specific path is exist there.

Now I think that right solution is that when the node application is started to invoke this functionality and keep the list of valid paths in some object which I can access very easy during the user call and check if path there.

my question is how to provide some event to the validator module when the node app(Server.js) is up to provide this object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a part of your application initialization, then you could read and parse this JSON file synchronously, using either `fs.readFileSync` and `JSON.parse`, or `require`:

```
var config = require('path/to/my/config.json');
```

Just make sure that the module handling this JSON loading is required in your application root before `app.listen` call.

In this case JSON data will be loaded and parsed by the time you server will start, and there will be no need to trouble yourself with callbacks or event emitters.

I can't see any benefits of loading your initial config asynchronously for two reasons:

1. The bottleneck of JSON parsing is the parser itself, but since it's synchronous, you won't gain anything here. So, the only part you'll be able to optimize is interactions with your file system (i.e. reading data from disk).
2. Your application won't be able to work properly until this data will be loaded.

## Update

If for some reason you can't make your initialization synchronous, you could delay starting your application until initialization is done.

The easiest solution here is to move `app.listen` part inside of initialization callback:

```js
// initialization.js
var glob = require('glob')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = function initialization (done) {
  var data = {}

  glob('./config/*.json', function (err, files) {
    if (err) throw err
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      var filename = path.basename(file)
      data[filename] = require(file)
    })
    done(data);
  })
}
```

```js
// server.js
var initialization = require('./initialization')
var app = require('express')()

initialization(function (data) {
  app.use(require('./my-middleware')(data))
  app.listen(8000)
})
```

An alternative solution is to use simple event emitter to signal that your data is ready:

```js
// config.js
var glob = require('glob')
var path = require('path')
var events = require('events')

var obj = new events.EventEmitter()
obj.data = {}

glob('./config/*.json', function (err, files) {
  if (err) throw err
  files.forEach(function (file) {
    var filename = path.basename(file)
    obj.data[filename] = require(file)
  })
  obj.emit('ready')
})

module.exports = obj
```

```js
// server.js
var config = require('./config')
var app = require('express')()

app.use(require('./my-middleware'))

config.on('ready', function () {
  app.listen(8000)
})
```

Comment: Thanks Leonid 1+ Assume that I need to do it via event (not to read it just via event invoke the functionlity ) and later on when I've some requests (via express) use this object which already parsed for validation,can you please provide example ? lets assume that I've more than one json files ...

Comment: I can't see any benefits of doing so. The bottleneck of JSON parsing is the parser itself, but since it's synchronous, you won't gain anything here. So, the only part you'll be able to optimize is interactions with your file system (i.e. reading data from disk). Another thing to consider is that your application won't be able to work properly until this data will be loaded. But if you insist, I could add a simple asynchronous example.

Comment: yes please can you please provide example how via event I can invoke from the server.js file another functionality in different module,this iwll be great!

Comment: HI again can you please see my updated post and tell me if you still disagree and way ? 2. In your example the event is from the same file lets assume that Ive already functionality which read the json files and return an object how would you invoke this via event from the server.js file ,Thanks  a lot!

Comment: @JhonDree I'm sorry, but your last edit and comment is not entirely clear for me. Do you want me to explain how to use exported async function from my example to get an actual data?

Comment: Hi I'll update it again please see if now its more clear,I think now its more straight forward...THanks for assitance!

Comment: @JhonDree the approach you described in your last edit looks perfectly fine. Buy why don't you want to load your config synchronously? It's the most common solution for your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84953/discussion-between-leonid-beschastny-and-jhon-dree).

Comment: @JhonDree sorry, I forgot to `require` it.